# How to remove redistributable dependencies?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I developed a windows based application (i.e. myapp) which is developed using Visual studio 10. When i try to run the tool on other systems, which doesn't 
have visual studio installation, i get an error that msvcr100.dll is missing.

so i tried including myapp.exe.local and copied the requested dll's in the same path  and tried, This time i got "the application was unable to start 
correctly (0xc000007b)"

This problem is seen when Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable Package is not properly configured.

I do not want to install the redistributables in the target system, as it is not recommended to do any kind of installation in target system.

Can i get any suggestion, if there is any possibility to run the tool without installing redistributables ?

Comment: You should be able to statically link the runtime into your application. Check your linker options.

Answer (score 0):

Right click your project name at the top of the solution explorer and choose properties.  Under "General", towards the top, make sure "Use of MFC" and "Use of ATL" are both set to static.  If tht doesn't work, look through the linker options that will let you choose static.